# Conditional Expressions for Objects when Debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use conditional expressions when debugging my C# code in VS Code (specifically, for Unity, if it matters). However, I'm not sure how to go about debugging objects. My first guess was to use an expression like this in the conditional breakpoint:

```
targetDistance == new Vector3(0, 1, 2);
```

However, when I use this expression, I get this error:

> Failed to evaluate expression in conditional breakpoint. Could not resolve type: Vector3

Any thoughts about how to go about doing this properly?

Comment: Dont use double equal signs when assigning values?

Comment: Have you tried entering the fully qualified name of Vector3 (including namespace)? @BugFinder a condition for a breakpoint it's not an assignment.

Comment: @BugFinder the question is about a **condition** for a **breakpoint** (so the debugger only holds at that breakpoint if the conditionis fulfilled) ;) it is a `bool` check, not an asignment ^^